# What makes the Air Force and Navy pilots different?

Tags: military, pilots

As far as I know, aviation in both divisions are almost the same. They fly various aircrafts, they do dogfights, air to ground attacks, air transports, electronic attacks, and more. Can you say that Air Force and Navy pilots are different in some ways?

Comment: VTC as too broad. I could list some differences in the procedures they use, but this is such an open question I doubt we could run out of minor things to add to such a list.

Comment: One is called a pilot, the other an [aviator](https://www.wearethemighty.com/military-culture/why-naval-pilots-prefer-aviator?rebelltitem=1#rebelltitem1)

Comment: One flies back to the same place, t'other flies back to the same place in a different location. If that doesn't work, one walks back, t'other swims back.

Comment: Naval Aviators are generally more handsome than their USAF brethren, and we don't sing when we get drunk.

Comment: I don't know, but I understand that one group sport wings of lead, the other wings of gold.

Answer (score 1):

Navel aviation pilots are specifically trained for anti ship and anti submarine warfare roles and they are also trained for carrier based operations. They are also trained for ground attack, dogfight etc. Air Force pilots does not have carrier based landing skills and they do not have anti submarine warfare capabilities.

Comment: Factually wrong, as [multiple air forces worldwide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lockheed_P-3_Orion#Operators) have had antisubmarine aircraft grouped under the airforce rather than the navy, even when the navy had aviation assets as well.

Comment: Naval pilots. Navel pilots are something completely different